# Chamar uma função javascript em arquivos ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express.js, ejs

Estou tentando criar no meu arquivo js uma função pra formatar uma data trocando o "-" para "/" e estou utilizando node.js e express da seguinte forma.

```
function formatDate(str){
    var format = str.toString().replace("-", "/");
    console.log(format);
    return format;
}
```

Este *refused.PERIODO_COBRANCA* esta vindo de um json

```
<td>
   <%= formatDate(refused.PERIODO_COBRANCA) %>
</td>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce esta enviando a funcao `formDate` como parametro de objeto no metodo `render()`?

Comment: @CmteCardeal não estou fazendo isso, fui testar aqui agora desta forma.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, eu testei da forma que você comentou, mas não consegui chegar no ponto de fazer da certo. Fiz da seguinte forma, res.render(AQUI DENTRO COLOQUEI MINHA FUNÇÃO). também fiz res.render(formatDate(str)) chamando a função dentro do render, mas não deu certo.

Comment: voce colocou a funcao dentro do objeto? desta forma: res.render('sua_view', { formDate: formDate }; ?

Comment: Amigo você não pode simplesmente chamar funções do backend assim... é preciso que você envie de alguma forma para o seu template. Como o @CmteCardeal sugeriu `res.render('./templates/customers/customer', { formDate: formDate })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário passar a referência da função para o contexto da View. Você pode passar a função como parâmetro da mesma forma que envia dados para a View, por exemplo: `res.render('myView', { formatDate })`.

Outra forma é utilizar o `app.locals` ou `res.locals` para disponibilizar a função dentro da sua view. A diferença está no ciclo de vida. O `app.locals` persiste ao longo da aplicação toda durante toda sua vida, já o `res.locals` persiste apenas durante o ciclo de vida de um response. Veja um exemplo:

```
function formatarValor(entrada) {
    return entrada.toUpperCase();
}

// Com a linha abaixo a função "formatarValor" fica disponível dentro da view
app.locals.formatarValor = formatarValor;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var dados = ['valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3', 'valor 4'];
    res.render('myView', { dadosDaView: dados });
});
```

Escrevi um pequeno texto sobre este cenário: https://medium.com/@marcelo.vismari/nodejs-express-ejs-como-usar-funcoes-durante-renderizacao-f51122e1eaca

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui fazer o queria com a ajuda do seu post.